# Get text from to VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, text

```
textbox1.text ="tradeIdno 268181090713],buyToken tradeIdno 748832411131],buyToken tradeIdno 81724814287],buyToken tradeIdno 4871814],buyToken"

Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
        s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("tradeIdno") + 3)
        s = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("buyToken"))
        MsgBox(s)
```

I want get string 268181090713 and newline 748832411131 and newline 81724814287 and newline 4871814

Comment: `(?<=)\d+[^\]]` [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches)

Comment: Btw, you can simply use `\d+` if there's nothing else that can get in the way.

Comment: Can you write the code

Comment: `Dim s = String.Join(ControlChars.NewLine, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(textbox1.Text, "(?<=)\d+[^\]]").Cast(Of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match).Select(Function(x) x.Value))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way with a for/next loop

```
textbox1.text ="tradeIdno 268181090713],buyToken tradeIdno 748832411131],buyToken tradeIdno 81724814287],buyToken tradeIdno 4871814],buyToken"

Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim result as string = ""
dim atnumeric as boolean = false

for x as integer = 0 to s.length - 1
     if isnumeric(string.substr(s,x,1))
          atnumeric = true
          result += string.substr(s, x, 1)
     else
         if atnumeric = true then
            result += vbcrlf
            atnumeric = false
     end if


next
msgbox(result)
```